# Firebase + Flutter - Cloud functions onCall result in "unauthenticated" error from Android app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed the following test `https.onCall` function to Cloud Functions on firebase - deployed using node 10:

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    return {
        "message": "Hello, world",
    }

});
```

This function returns as expected when tested from a node environment.

However, within my flutter (android) app - using the [Cloud functions plugin for Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/cloud_functions), I'm getting the following authentication error, despite being logged in (via phone number auth):

Flutter code:

```
void _checkAuth() async { 

    print("Check auth");
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    var user = await _auth.currentUser();

    print(user.toString());

    _testFunCall();
}

void _testFunCall() async {
    HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance
        .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'helloWorld');

    try {
        final HttpsCallableResult result = await callable.call();
        print(result.data);

    } on CloudFunctionsException catch (e) {
        print('caught firebase functions exception');
        print(e.code);
        print(e.message);
        print(e.details);
    } catch (e) {
        print('caught generic exception');
        print(e);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
I/flutter ( 4662): caught firebase functions exception
I/flutter ( 4662): UNAUTHENTICATED
I/flutter ( 4662): Unauthenticated
I/flutter ( 4662): null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Call this _checkAuth() method after user loggedIn with firebase. Then only you can get _auth.currentUser(); Otherwise user will be nil and unuthenticated only.

Comment: I am getting this exact error with the latest plugins in April 2020, anyone else?

Comment: Same here. Have you found any solution?

Comment: It's also happening to my team. We use node 12. Is this still a thing?

Comment: same problem in "node": "14"

Answer (score 2):

The problem was using Node 10 when deploying to cloud functions.

Node 10 is currently in beta. Switched down to node 8 and it works fine:

In `package.json` in your cloud functions dir, switch:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
```

to:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
```

Comment: Presumably they will update the status of the beta here - node 8 is currently the only recommended engine: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version

Comment: Unfortunately, this issue happens even with node 8

Comment: hey @AndreyGordeev, were you able to find the solution for tis issue