# Flutter app giving UNAUTHENTICATED errors when calling Firebase cloud functions directly

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I tried using firebase cloud functions oncall method directly from my FLUTTER app and it keeps giving me an UNAUTHENTICATED error even when I am logged in
Flutter app code

```
CloudFunctions function = CloudFunctions.instance;
final HttpsCallable createCallable = function.getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'two_create')
  ..timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30);

try {
  final HttpsCallableResult result = await createCallable.call({
    'stay': 'con50',
    'open': false
  });

  print(result.data);
}on CloudFunctionsException catch(e){
  print('-----------------------------------------------');
  print(e.code); print(e.message); print(e.details);
  print('-----------------------------------------------');
}

dynamic user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
print(user.uid);
```

I got this error

```
I/flutter (19466): -----------------------------------------------
I/flutter (19466): UNAUTHENTICATED
I/flutter (19466): UNAUTHENTICATED
I/flutter (19466): null
I/flutter (19466): -----------------------------------------------
I/flutter (19466): eMTX6OcYPOSeYdimmCSqjbnnmWM2
```

I tried printing out the uid to show I am currently signed in and I am currently using an android device for testing.

This is the function I am calling from my app

```
exports.two_create = functions.https.onCall(async (context,data)=>{
    var oncall = require('./httponcall');

    var text = await oncall.create(admin,allRef.one2,context,data);
    return text;
})
```

And I didn't get any logs from Firebase console when it was triggered

Comment: Please edit the question to show the function code that you're trying to invoke, and any logs that it might be generating.

Comment: If the function isn't actually being invoked (you find no logs), then contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: This might be a matter of Node version. Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120115/firebase-flutter-cloud-functions-oncall-result-in-unauthenticated-error-fr

Comment: I have the same issue!

Comment: I tried changing the node version I still got the same error

Comment: For me the issue was that the invoker was not set on https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/details/

Comment: I think @HannahStark is referring to this https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function, have you checked that?

Answer (score 2):

1. first update the firebase tools and dependencies to latest.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=0#set-up-node.js-and-the-firebase-cli

npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save

npm install -g firebase-tools

2. after deploy
3. go to Google cloud console(GCP) not the firebase console
   GCP sidebar > Cloud functions > select your function
   go to PERMISSIONS >ADD > "allUsers"> Firebase > Firebase Viewer

do this at your own risk iam not any cloud devloper . i dont know the risk of adding allUsers like this
iam new to flutter devlopment

[image]